# how to start event loop in shared library for Android?

Tags: qt, shared-libraries, qcoreapplication

I have created a shared library for Android with qt5.5.1, and it worked well.
but the slots function can not work, because there is no event loop in the library, so the signal-slot has no effect.
Anyone knows the way to solve this question?

Comment: Use `QEventLoop`?

Comment: yes ,ues QCoreApplication to start event loop ,i have tried this way:

Comment: this way :1、Create a new thread using std::thread (NOT a QThread)
2、In that thread, run a function that constructs the QCoreApplication, and then constructs the QSerialPort, and then call QCoreApplication::exec().

Comment: i see this advise,https://forum.qt.io/topic/65865/event-loop-in-library/4,

Comment: Is your DLL going to be used by a program that already runs Qt?

    If yes, then you cannot use QCoreApplication in your thread. Use a QThread, like @SGaist suggested.
    If no, then you must instantiate a QCoreApplication in your thread first, before you call QCoreApplication::exec(). (Also, you cannot use QThread. Use a std::thread instead)

Comment: i forget to say that i want to build this library for android.